# How to create an AAT table in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, advanced-license-level

A long time ago I used to create aat.dbf tables in ArcInfo by using the simple command "BUILD." 
I'm staring at ArcGIS 9.3 and I have no clue about how to perform this same, simple task!

Is there a quick way to do this?

Comment: The coverage format is archaic. Geodatabases work very differently (and always have attributes, so no BUILD is ever necessary).  You probably want to start with the intro documentation; since it's more evolution than spontaneous creation, it shouldn't be too hard to make forward progress with a little review.

Comment: for shapefiles? you can 'build' topology in geodatabase format http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/coverages/building-coverage-topology.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to work with a coverage within ArcGIS, or just wondering what the equivalent to an AAT table is in an ArcGIS feature class.

The equivalent of the AAT table in an ArcGIS feature class would be it's attribute table. It is created as part of the feature class creation process and doesn't need to be built. You add/remove columns and edit data using various tools, but there is no build process.

What I used to do in ArcGIS 9.3 is install ARC/INFO workstation alongside it and do any cleaning and building I needed to do in ARC/INFO, if I had coverage work to do.

If I remember correctly, I don't think any of the coverage tools that actually edit coverages in ArcGIS 9.3 work without an ARC/INFO license anyway.

I don't remember the licensing deal, but if you already have ArcGIS advanced, I can't imagine it would be that big a deal to also get the version of ARC/INFO workstation to complement it. That is my answer. That works a lot better than trying to simulate what you can do in Workstation in ArcGIS.

ARC/INFO is very quick to install when you already have ArcGIS Advanced.

Comment: basically, I would have a file of polygons and to get an aat.dbf table I would just BUILD "Line" instead of "poly". This new aat.dbf file would give me a list of polygons and the polygons they are adjacent too. I just can't believe this simple operation has been made more difficult!

Comment: Assuming you know how to use ArcGIS and have an ArcMap compatible piece of data, there are different options depending what version of ArcGIS you have. If you have one of the 10.x versions, you can use Polygon Neighbors.  Here is a [link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm).  If you only have 9.3, it is more complicated.  Here is a [link](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/64454)